# ECONNREFUSED error on sequelize migration with docker-compose

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose, sequelize.js

I'm trying to up a nodejs application that uses sequelize to manage a MySQL database. To do this, I used sequelize-cli.

When I run docker-compose, it builds the images correctly, but, at the time it starts the containers, the sequelize-cli cannot connect into MySQL database and make the migrations.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine

RUN mkdir /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3333

CMD yarn start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123123
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=test

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3333:3333'
    command: yarn start
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=database
      - DB_USER=root
    depends_on:
      - database
```

database.js

```
module.exports = {
  username: process.env.DB_USER || 'test',
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD || '123123',
  database: process.env.DB_NAME || 'test',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
}
```

package.json scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npx sequelize db:migrate && npx sequelize db:seed:all && node src/app/index.js"
  },
```

When I run `docker-compose up -d --build` I expect to see the containers running without problems. The database container created by docker-compose runs correctly, but the app container don't.

Running `docker logs <app_container_id>`, I have the following output:

```
yarn run v1.17.3

$ npx sequelize db:migrate && npx sequelize db:seed:all && node src/app/index.js

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.16.3, CLI: 5.4.0, ORM: 5.8.5]

Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".

ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.27.0.2:3306

error Command failed with exit code 1.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Docker-compose injects the database container IP into my app container environment variables, so why am I still get connection refused?

Comment: can you post your sequlize code?

Answer (score 1):

I know its kinda late, but all you have to do is change host from '172.27.0.2' to your db container name 'database'

Answer (score 0):

are you linking your docker containers? or are they part of the same network? you need yo verify the link between your database and your app container. make sure that you are connecting your 2 containers before running migrations.